# How does one determine if a spacetime is globally hyperbolic?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, causality

A spacetime $M$ is said to be [globally hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold) if it is strongly causal and if the sets $J^+(p)\cap J^-(q)$, for all $p,q\in M$, are compact. (For more information, see the Wiki article on [causal structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure).)

It may be shown that global hyperbolicity is equivalent to the existence of a [Cauchy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) in $M$.

Presumably the easiest method of checking that $M$ is globally hyperbolic is to find a Cauchy surface and somehow prove that it is a Cauchy surface. How does one actually do this? That is, given some 3-dimensional submanifold, how does one go about verifying that it is a Cauchy surface? Let's assume that I know the topology of $M$ and have knowledge of the metric everywhere (not in one coordinate patch).

Or is there a better method for checking the global hyperbolicity of $M$?

[Note that I know one can check all of the equivalent definitions for global hyperbolicity. What I don't know is how one could reasonably check any of them in practice.]

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is that if there was an easy way to tell if a space-time is globally hyperbolic, then the strong cosmic censorship conjecture wouldn't be that hard to prove.

Comment: Well maybe if there are no general ways to do it, heuristics and specific examples might be helpful.

Comment: http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/973/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01609469.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2FBF01609469&token2=exp=1458614619~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F973%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252FBF01609469.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252FBF01609469*~hmac=0774a711918976ab986c6a77d0678a844be4ea416a948219210fb5de9ff8f1f1

Comment: @yess The link above doesn't work. Is it possible to update this link?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. I dont remember what is the link about.

Comment: https://cds.cern.ch/record/536520/files/0201057.pdf